# How to get element index on the basis of its text using Java and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, webui

So there's a table of links on the web page, and I need the element indices. I know the names of the links. I tried the `selenium.getElementIndex().intValue()` command, hoping for an integer index. 
   But the `getElementIndex()` function requires a String locator as parameter. Not sure what to pass, since the only information about that element that I have is its name.
   Also, what kind of value does the `getElementIndex()` return?

Answer (score 2):

This code will return the index of an element relative to it's parent. Only siblings with the same tag will be counted

```
int getElementIndex(WebElement element) {
    WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
    List<WebElement> siblings = parent.findElements(By.xpath("./" + element.getTagName()));
    int i=0;
    for (WebElement sibling : siblings) {
        if (element.equals(sibling)) {
            return i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    throw new NotFoundException(); // Should never happen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [javadoc for `Selenium.getElementIndex()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getElementIndex%28java.lang.String%29).

It will return an `Number` which is the index of the element selected and takes a `String locator` which is used to locate the element you're interested in on the HTML page and can be a number of things eg: -

- the id of the element
- some xPath
- etc

[More details here.](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html)