# How to use getElementIndex using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can someone give a coding example of how to use this Selenium command?

`getElementIndex()`

More info:
https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/GetElementIndex.html.

If it has been deprecated, how would I know?

In other words, this code below is throwing an error as though it has been deprecated:

```
driver().findElement(By.id("id_value")).getElementIndex();
```

Comment: Curious but what is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: cannot resolve method 'getElementIndex()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GetElementIndex

[`GetElementIndex()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/GetElementIndex.html) class returns the index of an element. It is a part of [com.thoughtworks.selenium](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/package-summary.html) package and the [constructor](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/GetElementIndex.html#GetElementIndex-com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.ElementFinder-com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.JavascriptLibrary-) is as follows:

```
GetElementIndex(ElementFinder finder, JavascriptLibrary js)
```

But [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [java](/questions/tagged/java) client
is based on [org.openqa.selenium](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/package-summary.html) package.

---

### Conclusion

There is no equivalent method of `com.thoughtworks.selenium`'s `GetElementIndex()` in Selenium's Java client. However, you can always create your own customized methods.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:
The above code is for the HTML Selenium recorder (in Selenese), and not for the Java version of Selenium.
Someone else has already offered a java equivalent here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289125/1691651